# How to automatic generate variable in neovim like in Jetbrains IDEA

Tags: java, code-generation, neovim, vscode-snippets, nvim.cmp

1. when new a ArrayList in Jetbrains IDEA , like:

   ```java
     new ArrayList<String>()
   ```
2. then write  '.var' at last

   ```java
    new ArrayList<String>().var
   ```
3. then press Tab,IDEA automatic generate the local variable

   ```java
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
   ```
4. Question: if use neovim, is there any plugin for this scene?
   now i use Luasnip plugin and friendly-snippets plugin

Comment: Have you tried doing a search for "auto complete" or intellisense plugins?

Comment: yes intellisense plugin